# Swift: How to add localization on enum values?

Tags: swift, enums, localization

I try to add localization on my app in SwiftUI, and it is working fine on pure Text("..."). But not worked on enums.

I use enum's value like below, `header.name.text = HomeSection.allCases[indexPath.section].rawValue`. And I did an experiment on case1 - NowPlaying, however it is not working, the text "NowPlayingSection" is showed after app is launched.

So what should I do to deal with enum on localization?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
            switch kind {
            case UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader:
                guard let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: HeaderView.reuseId, for: indexPath) as? HeaderView else {
                    return UICollectionReusableView()
                }
                header.name.text = HomeSection.allCases[indexPath.section].rawValue
                header.onSeeAllClicked = { [weak self] in
                    print("%%% Click %$$$$")
                    self?.parent.seeAllforSection(HomeSection.allCases[indexPath.section])
                }
                return header
            default:
                return UICollectionReusableView()
            }
        }
```

### Enums

```
enum HomeSection: String, CaseIterable {
    case NowPlaying = "NowPlayingSection"
    case Popular
    case Upcoming
    case TopActor = "Hot Actors"
}
```

### Localizable.strings

```
"NowPlayingSection" = "Now playing";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually what you do is not a SwiftUI part, so use with `NSLocalizedString`

```
header.name.text = 
   NSLocalizedString(HomeSection.allCases[indexPath.section].rawValue, 
       comment: "")
```

Comment: Yeah, it is an UIKit (UICollectionVIew) wrapped in SwiftUI. It is working now, I would remove the SwiftUI tag, thanks, Asperi!